# Is there a way to get a localized string from the platform device from a Webview?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, webview

I have an app that has a WebView.   For reasons not needed in this thread, i need to localize some strings.  Simple enough, though I am not allowed to use extract and use any translation services normally at our disposal.

Manager wants me to see if i can leverage the Platform device (IPad/IPhone) to convert the my strings to English, Spanish, Simplified Chinese, and Japanese.  They are simple strings too, such as "Cancel", "Start", "Stop".  I was thinking that the device did have some sort of localization tools i could use to do these easy conversions, but i wasn't sure.

Is this doable?  I think so.   Does anyone know how to do it?

Right now, i'm not an objective C programmer, so i can easily set up a call to C++ from the javascript which would handle the translation calls.  I just don't know how much into Objective C i am allowed to do, or need to do to accomplish this task.

Comment: Are you using the web view to display HTML included in the project or are you trying to load a webpage and then modifying its contents? The former might be doable, I would be surprised if the latter were realistic.

Comment: Im using the Webview to run HTML included in the project.  So, I was going to add some calls, but i didnt know there was a way via C++ to get to the Devices Built in Language packs.